# How multiple input works in Codeigniter 3, in the database file upload only one, not many files?

Tags: codeigniter, web, codeigniter-3

plaese help me dear,
I want to try enabling multiple input on other titles and other upload files.
Is there something wrong with the controller that I made, so it loops for other titles and multiple files, only one of which is uploaded to the database?

## This my View of code

```
<!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <label for="otitle">Other</label>
                                <div class="form-row add-container">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="other_title[]" placeholder="Input title" multiple>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-5">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="other_file[]" id="" multiple>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                        <a class="btn add-comp" style="border: 0; padding: 10px;"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="color: #006CF8;"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<!-- End Modal -->
```

## This is my Controller for my code

```
public function actionBible($type, $id = null)
    {
        $id_kategori = $this->input->post('id_kategori');
        $id_kategori = $id_kategori == NULL ? $this->input->post('nama_kategori') : $id_kategori;

        $data = array(
            'nama_bible' => $this->input->post('nama_bible'),
            'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
            'datasheet_title' => $this->input->post('datasheet_title'),
            'manual_title' => $this->input->post('manual_title'),
            'id_kategori' => $id_kategori,
            'created_by' => $this->session->userdata('nama_user'),
        );

        $folderUpload = "./uploads/bible/";
        $files = $_FILES;

        // datasheet
        $namaFile = $files['file']['name'];
        $lokasiTmp = $files['file']['tmp_name'];
        // # kita tambahkan uniqid() agar nama gambar bersifat unik
        $namaBaru = uniqid() . '-' . $namaFile;
        $lokasiBaru = "{$folderUpload}/{$namaBaru}";
        move_uploaded_file($lokasiTmp, $lokasiBaru);
        // manual
        $namaFileManual = $files['manual_file']['name'];
        $lokasiTmpManual = $files['manual_file']['tmp_name'];
        // # kita tambahkan uniqid() agar nama gambar bersifat unik
        $namaBaruManual = uniqid() . '-' . $namaFileManual;
        $lokasiBaruManual = "{$folderUpload}/{$namaBaruManual}";
        move_uploaded_file($lokasiTmpManual, $lokasiBaruManual);

        // datasheet
        $ktp = array('file' => $namaBaru);
        if ($namaFile != NULL) {
            $data = array_merge($data, $ktp);
        }
        // manual
        $manual = array('manual' => $namaBaruManual);
        if ($namaFileManual != NULL) {
            $data = array_merge($data, $manual);
        }

        // var_dump($data);
        if ($type == 'add') {
            $store = $this->db->insert('tb_bible', $data);
            if ($store) {
                // attachments
                $getLastId = $this->db->order_by('id_bible', 'DESC')->limit(1)->get('tb_bible')->row_array();

                $files = $_FILES;
                $jumlahFile = count($files['other_file']['name']);
                $other_title = $this->input->post('other_title');
                for ($i = 0; $i < $jumlahFile; $i++) {
                    $data = array(
                        'id_bible' => $getLastId['id_bible'],
                        'id_other' => $this->input->post('id_other'),
                        'other_title' => $other_title[$i],
                        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                    );
                    $folderUpload = "./uploads/upnormal/";
                    $files = $_FILES;

                    $namaFileOther = $files['other_file']['name'][$i];
                    $lokasiTmpOther = $files['other_file']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    // # kita tambahkan uniqid() agar nama gambar bersifat unik
                    $namaBaruOther = uniqid() . '-' . $namaFileOther;
                    $lokasiBaruOther = "{$folderUpload}/{$namaBaruOther}";
                    move_uploaded_file($lokasiTmpOther, $lokasiBaruOther);

                    $other = array('other' => $namaBaruOther); // mengambil nama baru dan di upload ke dalam databases
                    if ($namaFileOther != NULL) {
                        $data = array_merge($data, $other);
                        $this->db->insert('tb_other_bible', $data);
                    }
                }
            }
        } elseif ($type == 'edit') {
            $this->db->update('tb_bible', $data, ['id_bible' => $this->input->post('id_bible')]);
        } else {
            $data = array(
                'delete' => 1
            );
            $this->db->update('tb_bible', $data, ['id_bible' => decrypt_url($id)]);
        }
        $this->session->set_flashdata('messageAlert', $this->messageAlert('success', "Data $type"));
        redirect('bible/guide');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `multiple` attribute is not supported on `<input type="text"` . See [MDN docs for multiple attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/multiple)

File input fields allow multiple files to be selected.
But text input fields DO NOT allow multiple values to be entered.

So, if you would like to allow the user to enter titles for every file that they select, you will need to change your design so that the number of text inputs changes based on the number of files that are selected. This could be done with JavaScript that listens for change events on the file input element.